# Hibernate Restricitions.ilike runs into error

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

Executing the following restrictions runs into following error

```
 Message: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

       if (suburbid > 0) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("suburb.id", suburbid));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use iLike for integer change it to eq.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("address.subrub.id", suburbid));
```

to

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("suburb.id", suburbid));
```

**UPDATE**

Also try to change

```
.createAlias("development.address.suburb", "suburb");
```

to

```
.createAlias("devAddress.suburb", "suburb");
```

Comment: it is not id of address. It is id of suburb which is in the address class